# Spring Boot Redirect Url

Tags: java, angular, jsp, spring-boot

Sorry for my english, I am creating a spring boot application and in welcome controller i had written code for forward and redirect but the problem is that i am just able to load html pages only jsp pages are not getting displayed it's showing 404  error. how do i make both working?

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{id:[^\\.]*}")
    public String html5Forwarding() {
        return "forward:/index.*";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.*";
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe you still need `ModelAndView`? dont you . correct me if am wrong?

Comment: can you post the url, that is producing 404? and maybe 1 url that is working as expected?

Comment: Please provide your application.properties and pom.xml file

Comment: @manfromnowhere i just had 3 jsp file it just contain somelogic not much view so no need of modeland view

Comment: @JohnnyAW working url is http://localhost:9090/test/login and not working url is http://localhost:9090/test/patternpage.jsp

Comment: @vineeth sivan will provide files to you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

```
return "forward:/"; --- 1, and 
return "index"; ---2
```

Comment: do you have dependencies for both thymeleaf and jsp? if can you share pom and view resolver?

Comment: No i dont want to use thymeleaf

Comment: Add below dependency for jsp 
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     </dependency>

Comment: below view resolver
@Bean
 public ViewResolver getViewResolverJSP() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  resolver.setOrder(100);
  return resolver;
 }
create one source folder src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

Comment: I have added one example project to my git you can check if it works for you
https://github.com/Ravenloup/springboot-multi-view

Comment: adding ViewResolver will stop my html page and i want both html and jsp , and i your example you are using thymeleaf that i don't want to use

Comment: see for html too you need templeting engine and thymeleaf will be that, using thymeleaf means using thymeleaf tags and stuff but if you keep your view as pure html, I think it will be ok, I will try to find some other solution but I don't think there is any you need one view resolver for html